# next export : Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Registry' has already been declared

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I do `next build && next export` and serve the export like `serve -p 3001 out` I see following in the console and browser tab is blank (white)

> `_app-fe2f21502718f029.js:183 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Registry' has already been declared`

Things used to work fine with `next export` before on the same project. I have following version of `next` specified.

`"next": "^12.3.4",`

It is been a while I tested `next export` so it is hard for me to track down what commit caused this. Does anyone have ideas to narrow things down to what caused this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking in the `_app-fe2f21502718f029.js:183` was able identify this file was coming from dependency `pdfkit` which was used by `@react-pdf/renderer`, removing that dependency fixed the issue for me.